# Show the limit exists.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

For $|z|\neq 1$,show that the following limit exists:   $$f(z)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(z^n -1)}{(z^n+1)}$$
Is it possible to define f(z) when $|z|\neq 1$ in such a way as to make $f$ continuous?

Could anyone tell me how to start this problem? Should I multiples $\frac{z^n+1}{z^n+1}$ in the limit?

Thank you!

Comment: Cases: (i) $|z|\lt 1$; (ii) $|z|\gt 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide the cases into when (i)$|z|>1$, and (ii)$|z|<1$

Thinking of $|z|^n$ as a geometric sequence,

For (i), the limit should converge to $1$.
For (ii) the limit should converge to $-1$.